# How do LCDs power a specific pixel?

Tags: lcd, display

I have a vague idea of how LCDs turn on and off, but I still don't understand how an individual pixel could be turned on and off without having like tiny wires behind each etched area (which can't be correct since you can have LCDs be translucent). How exactly is a specific pixel targetted?

Comment: https://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/working-of-lcd.gif

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LCDs do have transparent wires, or rather, transparent film of indium tin oxide (ITO), which is used as conductive paths for each pixel.

ITO is the most widely used material due to its electrical conductivity, optical transparency and ease of use.

In simple displays there might be a single common conductive ITO backplane deposited on glass as the other electrode, and for each segment there is a wiring of ITO deposited as the other electrode, and the electrical ITO connections are made available at the edge of glass where further connections can be made. A segment is turned on by driving it with AC waveform to align the liquid crystals between under the electrodes.

More complex displays such as matrix LCDs may have multiple backplanes to allow the use of multiplexing of driving the display. Some LCDs may have a controller chip mounted onboard the glass to drive the common and segment terminals while providing a easy digital interface such as SPI or I2C.

Comment: This is only a comment, not an answer. Question is "How exactly is a specific pixel targeted?", not how is it connected to.

Comment: Why indium tin oxide, specifically?

Comment: @user253751 Because it's a conductive transparent material; I don't think there's anything to it beyond that.

Comment: Ok that helps, but is there like an individual trace made in the ITO for each segment or pixel, or is the state of a particular pixel changed through some kind of neat trick? I'm trying to wrap my head around things like the Nokia LCD display where it's alot of pixels packed together, cus I can't envision a single trace for each one

Comment: @0x777C That's covered in my answer about more complex displays being organized as a matrix. Now since you specifically asked, the Nokia LCD display has an onboard LCD controller/driver chip similar to PCD8544 which has 84 column drivers and 48 row drivers, meaning the display pixels are organized as a 84 by 48 matrix. Thus it only needs 84 row wires and 48 column wires, totalling only 132 wires to drive 4032 segments/pixels.

Comment: Thanks for this, you made me realise I don't know how matrices work and once I figured that out things made more sense